# Email/Password Authentication - Object not a function (Firebase and React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have firebase setup in my react app and am able to successfully read and write data to the database. However, I am trying to setup authentication with email and password and am receiving the following error-

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

What am i missing? My code is as follows

**Firebase.js file**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase (removed actual info for confidentiality)
const config = {
    apiKey: "api key here",
    authDomain: "domain here",
    databaseURL: "database url here",
    projectId: "id here",
    storageBucket: "storage bucket here",
    messagingSenderId: "sender Id here "
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default firebase;

export const database = firebase.database();
export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

Signup.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Link, Route } from 'react-router';
import { database, auth } from '../firebase';

class Signup extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // Bind custom methods to object context
        this.signup = this.signup.bind(this)
        // Create firebase database ref
        this.usersRef = database.ref('/users');
        // Set initial state
        this.state = {
          email: '',
          password: '',
          confirmPassword: '',
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Set restaurant state from db
        this.usersRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            this.setState({ users: snapshot.val( )});
        });
    }

    // User Signup
    signup(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("signed up")
          });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // Sign up form is here along, signup functon is called upon hitting submit
        )
    }
}

export default Signup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its this `auth.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

Comment: Oh man. Thanks! I was pasting in from firebase documentation and just left it in there. Silly mistake, I appreciate you pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **change**

> import firebase from 'firebase';`

to

> import firebase from 'firebase/**app**';